# What does the "X2[,Out]" and " = <ufunc 'copysign'>" mean in this doc page?

Tags: python, numpy

[numpy.copysign](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.copysign.html)

I know how this function works, but I can't fully understand what this title description mean.

Like

> x2[, out]

what does this parameter mean? Is it a datatype in python?

and

> " = <  ufunc 'copysign'> "

I have see something like this several times when I look through the documents.
Can anybody help? Thank you so much.

Comment: In regards to `[, out]` you will notice in the documentation: "out : ndarray, optional". Optional arguments are presented in square brackets. This is common to python in general. The representation gets a bit messy if they have to be supplied in order, for example `datetime.replace([year[, month[, day[, hour[, minute[, second[, microsecond[, tzinfo]]]]]]]])`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The brackets are standard Python documentation syntax for optional parameters to a function call. From the [Python Language Reference Introduction](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/introduction.html#notation):

> a phrase enclosed in square brackets (`[ ]`) means zero or one occurrences (in other words, the enclosed phrase is optional)

You'll notice it all over the place in Python & its libraries' documentation.

The `= <ufunc 'func_name'>` bit is to let you know that the function is an instance of the `numpy.ufunc` class. From the [NumPy docs on Universal Functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/ufuncs.html):

> A universal function (or ufunc for short) is a function that operates
>   on `ndarrays` in an element-by-element fashion, supporting array
>   broadcasting, type casting, and several other standard features. That
>   is, a ufunc is a “vectorized” wrapper for a function that takes a
>   fixed number of scalar inputs and produces a fixed number of scalar
>   outputs.
>
> In NumPy, universal functions are instances of the `numpy.ufunc` class. Many of the built-in functions are implemented in compiled C code, but `ufunc` instances can also be produced using the `frompyfunc` factory function.